# Keras Gates in Cell LSTM

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I tried using the lstm layer in keras. I need manipulate the gates at forget gate, input gate and output gate. I don't find a local to manipulate the variables of the gates. Anybody know if is possible to do in keras layers?

Answer (score 0):

Please have a look at the implementation of *[An Empirical Exploration of Recurrent Network Architectures](http://proceedings.mlr.press/v37/jozefowicz15.pdf)* where the users look into various formulation of LSTM to investigate the alternative units as well as study the importance of each three gates. The came up with three variants of LSTM, namely MUT1,2,3 which each outperformed the original unit in different cases, except language modeling.

Please look into the code [here](https://github.com/sonyisme/keras-recommendation/blob/e84fab6706faf8405f4bfc75cf50ecff6433eb77/keras-master/keras/layers/recurrent.py) and compare the implementation with respect to the formula to see how to tweak the code according to what you have in mind.